# Not able to start Grails 2.3.1 Application from GGTS 3.4

Tags: grails, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I am using Grails 2.3.1 and GGTS 3.4

When I try to start the grails application from within GGTS I get the below error

If I run the application from command line it works fine. I also tried to create the application from within GGTS and it also gives the same below error.

I tried deleting the folder for .slcache and also restarted the machine but same issue. Could not find reference for this issue elsewhere. Is this an issue

```
 Loading Grails 2.3.1
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to development.....
| Packaging Grails application.....
| Running Grails application
| Error java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Admin\.grails\2.3.1\.slcache\.index (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process)
| Error     at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
| Error     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:212)
| Error     at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:107)
| Error     at org.springsource.loaded.MethodInvokerRewriter.addToCacheIndex(MethodInvokerRewriter.java:379)
| Error     at org.springsource.loaded.MethodInvokerRewriter.rewrite(MethodInvokerRewriter.java:321)
| Error     at org.springsource.loaded.MethodInvokerRewriter.rewriteUsingCache(MethodInvokerRewriter.java:154)
| Error     at org.springsource.loaded.TypeRegistry.methodCallRewriteUseCacheIfAvailable(TypeRegistry.java:791)
| Error     at org.springsource.loaded.agent.SpringLoadedPreProcessor.preProcess(SpringLoadedPreProcessor.java:265)
| Error     at org.springsource.loaded.agent.ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.transform(ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.java:102)
| Error     at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
| Error     at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:424)
| Error     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
| Error     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
| Error     at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
| Error     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
| Error     at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
| Error     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
| Error     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
| Error     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
| Error     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
| Error     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
| Error     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
| Error     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
| Error     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
| Error     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
| Error     at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
| Error     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
| Error     at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
| Error     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
| Error     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
| Error     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
| Error     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
| Error     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
| Error     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
| Error     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
| Error     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
| Error     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
| Error     at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
| Error     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
| Error     at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
| Error     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
| Error     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
| Error     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
| Error     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
| Error     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
| Error     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
| Error     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
| Error     at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:44)
| Error     at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
| Error     at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:156)
| Error     at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:291)
| Error     at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$getLog.call(Unknown Source)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
| Error     at org.grails.plugins.tomcat.fork.ForkedTomcatServer.<clinit>(ForkedTomcatServer.groovy:39)
```

Comment: Maybe you're running in the command line and GGTS at the same time?

Comment: Grails 2.3.1 set the persmission of the executalbe to everyone ?

Comment: 1. Try running the grails CLEAN command
2. Restart your IDE and app

Answer (score 0):

It's an old thread but it may help someone.

There's seems to be a problem with **.grails** folder located in the home directory.

- Either it **doesn't** **exist**. If it's so then **create** one.
- Or you don't have **permission** to access that .grails folder. It it's so then change the permission using **chown** command.

After completing either of the above steps, **clean** your grails project and **restart** your IDE.